# Triangle Proof Involving The Triangle Inequality

Tags: geometry, triangles

In triangle $ABC$, the medians $\overline{AD}$, $\overline{BE}$, and $\overline{CF}$ concur at the centroid $G$.

(a) Prove that $AD < (AB + AC)/2$.

(b) Let $P=AB+AC+BC$ be the perimeter of $\triangle ABC.$ Prove that
$$\frac{3P}{4} < AD + BE + CF < P.$$

---

I think I should apply the Triangle Inequality in here, but where?  Should I connect some points?  Make new triangles?  I'm stuck, thanks in advance!

Comment: see [inequality between median length and perimeter](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1760826/inequality-between-median-length-and-perimeter).

Comment: see the final proof in (https://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Geometry-proofs/Geometry_proofs.faq.question.448086.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following mystic hexagon:

[image]

By applying the triangle inequality to $ABA'$, we get $2\cdot AD<AB+BA' = AB+AC$.

That leads to $AD+BE+CF < AB+AC+BC$.
 On the other hand, $B$ is the centroid of $AA'A''$, hence

$$ \frac{3}{2}BA+\frac{3}{2}BA'+\frac{3}{2}BA'' < AA'+AA''+A'A'' = 2(AD+BE+CF).$$